# Cannot update Entity Framework virtual list objects

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, repository

I'll try explain simply my Entity Framework model. I have a User object which has a collection of zero or more UserInterest objects. Each user interest object has only three properties, unique ID, User Id and Description.

Whenever the user updates the User object, it should also update the related UserInterest objects but because these are free form (ie not part of a list of allowed interests), I want the user to pass in a list of type "string" to the webmethod of the names of all their interests. The code would ideally then look at the users existing list of interests, remove any that were no longer relevant and add in new ones and leave the ones which already exist.

My object model definitions

```
[Table("User")]
public class DbUser {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<DbUserInterest> Interests { get; set; }
}

[Table("UserInterest")]
public class DbUserInterest : IEntityComparable<DbUserInterest>
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public virtual DbUser User { get; set; }
    public int? UserId { get; set; }
}
```

The context Fluent mappings

```
modelBuilder.Entity<DbUser>()
    .HasKey(u => u.UserId);
modelBuilder.Entity<DbUser>()
    .Property(u => u.UserId)
    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
modelBuilder.Entity<DbUser>()
    .HasMany(u => u.Interests)
    .WithRequired(p => p.User)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

modelBuilder.Entity<DbUserInterest>()
    .HasKey(p => p.Id);
modelBuilder.Entity<DbUserInterest>()
    .Property(p => p.Id)
    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
modelBuilder.Entity<DbUserInterest>()
    .HasRequired(p => p.User)
    .WithMany(u => u.Interests)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

And lastly my webmethod code and repository method to do the update

```
public UpdateUserProfileDetailsResponse UpdateUserProfileDetails(UpdateUserProfileDetailsRequest request)
{
    try
    {
        var dbItem = _userDataRepository.GetItem(request.Header.UserId);

        dbItem.Interests.Clear();
        foreach (var dbInterest in request.UserInterests)
            dbItem.Interests.Add(new DbUserInterest { Name = dbInterest, UserId = dbItem.UserId});

        _userDataRepository.UpdateItem(dbItem);
        _userDataRepository.Save();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}

public override bool UpdateItem(DbUser item)
{
    var dbItem = GetItem(item.UserId);
    if (dbItem == null)
        throw new DataRepositoryException("User not found to update", "UserDataRepository.UpdateItem");

    var dbInterests = Work.Context.UserInterests.Where(b => b.UserId == item.UserId).ToList();
    var interestsToRemove = (from interest in dbInterests let found = item.Interests.Any(p => p.IsSame(interest)) where !found select interest).ToList();
    var interestsToAdd = (from interest in item.Interests let found = dbInterests.Any(p => p.IsSame(interest)) where !found select interest).ToList();

    foreach (var interest in interestsToRemove)
        Work.Context.UserInterests.Remove(interest);

    foreach (var interest in interestsToAdd)
    {
        interest.UserId = item.UserId;
        Work.Context.UserInterests.Add(interest);
    }                

    Work.Context.Entry(dbItem).State = EntityState.Modified;
    return Work.Context.Entry(dbItem).GetValidationResult().IsValid;
}
```

When I run this, at the `Repository.Save()` line I get the exception

```
Assert.IsTrue failed. An unexpected error occurred: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
```

But interestingly in the webmethod if I comment out the line `dbItem.Interests.Clear();` it doesn't throw an error, although then of course you get duplicates or extra items as it thinks everything is a new interest to add. However removing this line is the only way I can get the code to not error

Before, I had the UserId property of the Interest object set to non nullable and then the error was slightly different, something about you cannot change the relationship of a foreign key entity that is non nullable, which is why I changed the property to nullable but still no go.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What was the inner exception?

Comment: It was null annoyingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just clear the collection and then try to rebuild it. EF doesn't work that way. The `DbContext` keeps track of all of the objects that were brought back from the database in its Change Tracker. Doing it your way will of course cause duplicates because EF sees that they're not in the Change Tracker at all so they must be brand new objects necessitating being added to the database.

You'll need to either do the add/remove logic in your `UpdateUserProfileDetails` method, or else you have to find a way to pass `request.UserInterests` into your `UpdateItem` method. Because you need to adjust the existing entities, not the ones found on the request (which EF thinks are new).

Comment: Thanks, that explains it nicely

Answer (score 0):

you could try in this way
remove

```
dbItem.Interests.Clear();
```

then

```
    foreach (var dbInterest in request.UserInterests){
      if(dbItem.Interests.Any()){
        if (dbItem.Interests.Count(i=> i.Name==dbInterest && i.UserId==dbItem.UserId) == 0){
          dbItem.Interests.Add(new DbUserInterest { Name = dbInterest, UserId = dbItem.UserId});
        }
      }
   }
```